# Deleting both local child entities and DB child entities in EF6

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, master-detail

Using Entity Framework 6, I've got master and detail entities. I have a WinForm that displays the detail data in a grid for a given master entity. The context is held throughout the lifetime of the form.

The detail list is bound to the grid with a BindingList:

```
detailBindingSource = new BindingSource();
detailBindingList = new BindingList<Detail>(master.Details);
detailBindingSource.DataSource = detailBindingList;
detailGrid.SetDataBinding(detailBindingSource, "");
```

When the user deletes a row in the grid, the following code deletes the detail (the comments being my interpretation of what I *think* the code does):

```
var row = detailGrid.GetRow();         // Get the currently selected row in the detail grid
var detail = (Detail)row.DataRow;      // Get the entity related to the row
row.Delete();                          // This will delete the line from the list, but not from the DB
if (detail.ID > 0)                     // Don't try to delete a row that's only been added in memory and not to the DB
    dbset.Remove(detail);              // This will mark the entity to be deleted from the DB
```

And when the user is finished the changes are saved:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

All works well if I delete existing rows and save. All works well if I delete rows that have been added within the lifetime of the form/context and save. But if I do both -- delete an existing row and delete a newly-added-and-not-yet-saved row -- I get the following exception on saving:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Searching for information on the exception, I've found several references to how deleting from the a parent entity's navigation list isn't enough to delete the entity itself, but I thought the call to Remove in the code above addressed that (and it seems to if I only delete existing rows).

Does anyone know why it's only when deleting rows of each type (new and old) that the exception occurs?

Comment: I think you get this error, because you try to delete the new record that HAS NOT YET an ID , because the context is not saved. So you add a record and Try to delete from entity somethig that exist just in DataGridView.

Comment: I save any new row on Leave Event from row, and if you want to click delete, you can do it :) and will be deleted, because already is saved in context ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer why the error is occurring (or perhaps why it isn't occurring in some scenarios), but a solution is to detach the newly added lines that aren't in the database:

```
if (detail.ID > 0)
    dbset.Remove(detail);
else
    dbset.Detach(detail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the existing row you are deleting the same on all three tests? I mean, is it the same row with the same underlying data, same relationships?
It seems that on the third test, the existing row you are deleting has a relation to another table, who itself has a non nullable relation to a third table. When the relation disapears the corresponding row(s) on the third table needs to be removed as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but they are the same rows, and the child rows aren't related to anything other than the parent row.

Comment: Are you creating any child rows when you create de parent rows? If so, try explicitly deleting the associated child rows when you delete the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you Created and delete the context, as you should, you will have no problems. Don't use global contexts.